# grunt-contrib-concat: how to use option "process"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am writing build system using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for a Javascript library (Widget) that would concatenate, minify and package the files for distribution.

In the concatenation step I wanted to insert current date into one of the JS files with process option of [grunt-contrib-concat](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-concat), where it is stated:

> Type: Boolean Object Default: false
>
> Process source files as templates before concatenating.
>
> - false - No processing will occur.
> - true - Process source files using grunt.template.process defaults.
> - options object - Process source files using grunt.template.process, using the specified options.
> - function(src, filepath) - Process source files using the given function, called once for each file. The returned value will be used
>     as source code.
>
> (Default processing options are explained in the
>   grunt.template.process documentation)

Concat part from Gruntfile.js:

```
    concat: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: {
                block: true
            },
            process: true,
            separator: '\n /* ----- */ \n',
            banner: '<%= meta.banner %>'
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['src/Utility.js', 'src/MainClass.js', 'src/ViewClass.js', 'src/exif.js'],
            dest: 'build/Viewer.js'
        }
    },
```

I put the following line the Utility.js:

```
viewer.build_date = '<% grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>';
```

I expected that the string would get replaced by current date but it was empty after concatenation.

```
viewer.build_date = '';
```

grunt version 0.4.1 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you missing '=' before grunt sign as given below.

```
<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>
```